# Get creative type as video or image using Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried to get the type of creative(Image or Video) under a ad using Facebook API. I used this article as a reference https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative for making get request. I can't able to get the field which is mentioning the creative type. Please help me with this.

Comment: Are you talking about the `object_type`? And what was the request you tried? Don't just tell us _that_ you tried something, tell us what it actually was.

Comment: Apologize, Its the `object_type`. I am able to get that fields. Thanks